# PHP mail opens in Gmail but not in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, gmail, php

When I send a mail with PHP it displays correct in Gmail but not in Outlook. It's a mail with a PDF attachment and some text. The PDF is created with fpdf and sent as an attachment, this works fine in Gmail and Outlook.

The only problem there is, in Gmail the text of the emails is displayed correctly and in Outlook it's just a blank page and the text is an extra attachment.

Here is my code:

```
// encode data 
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

// email stuff (change data below)
$to = $contactEmail; 
$from = $myEmail; 
$subject = "MySubjectHere"; 
$message = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html><head></head><body>
            <p>Hi '$contactName.',</p><br>
            <p>Please find your pdf attached per your request.</p>
            <p>Feel free to call or email if you have any questions.</p>
            <p>Kind regards,</p><br>
            <p>MyNameHere</p>
            <p><strong>Manager</strong></p>
            <img alt="image" src="http://LinkToImage.png"/>
            <p style="color:#76923c;">
            <strong>P:</strong> 01 2345 6789| 
            <strong>W:</strong> <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">www.example.com</a></p>
            <p style="color:#76923c;">
            <strong>A:</strong> 94 Test Street. 
            </p></body></html>';

// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = $id."_".str_replace(" ","_",$Name).'.pdf';

// main header
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "Bcc: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

// no more headers after this, we start the body! //

$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;

// message
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";

// send message
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: I have a question. How will you able to send and receive email to outlook using php? Thank you

Comment: yes you will. You just need to make sure the header is correct and there are 2 end of line s at the end of the message.
If you're structure is correct, you'll be able to view mails in all clients.

Comment: How? I try to send email to outlook but I didn't receive anything. Should I put the SMTP server and port?

Comment: make sure the settings of your mail server are correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found where it went wrong:

```
 $body .= $message.$eol;
```

Should be

```
 $body .= $message.$eol.$eol;
```

Finally found it after 3 days!
 
Thanks for the responses anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
$to = $contactEmail; 
$from = $myEmail; 
$boundary = md5(date('r', time()));
$msg  = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
$msg .= "--$boundary\n";
$msg .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes\n";
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$msg .= "<h1>Website Enquiry</h1>
            <p><strong>Name:</strong> $name<br />
            <strong>Email:</strong> $email<br />
            <strong>Phone:</strong> $phone<br />
            <strong>Subject Name:</strong> $subject<br />
            <strong>Question:</strong> $question</p>";

$e_headers = "From: " . $from . "\n";
$e_headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$e_headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\n";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $e_headers);
```

This is the code I would use for a HTML contact form.
You shouldn't need to pass the content through the PHP_EOL, just the attachment

Answer (score 0):

```
$separator = md5(time());
$eol = "\r\n";
$message="";  // Always empty
$mailmessage="<h1>Yes got it</h1>";  //html content

$headers = "From: ".$email.$eol;
$headers .= "Bcc:". $Bcc. "\n";
$headers .= "Cc:". $cc. "\n"; 
$headers .= "Return-Path: <".$email.">\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;

$body .= "--" . $separator . "\r\n";
$body .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$body .= $message . "\r\n";

$body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";
$body .= $mailmessage . $eol.$eol;

$body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $file . "\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
$body .= $content . $eol;
$body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```